# How to read string and call function from a separate file, python 3

Tags: python-3.x, function, if-statement

I have a file `three_ways.py`. There I have 3 functions for calculating 3 different `y`.

```
# The content of error_metrics.py

def way_1(x1, x2):
    y = x1 - x2
    return y

def way_2(x1, x2)
    y = x1 ** 2 - x2 ** 2 
    return y

def way_3(x1, x2)
    y = x1 * x2
    return y
```

In my main (another) py-file, I want to design a function `get_y()`. It accepts a string argument to control which way to use.

```
way = 'way_2'
y = get_y(x1, x2, way)
```

I could use if-elif statement, see below. But I want avoid using if-elif. Because there can be arbitrary number of functions of different `way_n()`, n can be any number. Whenever I add a `way_x()` function in the file `three_ways.py`, I will have to make another `elif` statement in the function `get_y()`. And when `n` gets larger, the whole codes will be hard to read.

```
# starting point for making the function of get_y()
import three_ways

def get_y(x1, x2, way):
    if way == 'way_1':
        y = three_ways.way_1(x1, x2)
    elif way == 'way_2':
        y = three_ways.way_2(x1, x2)
    elif way == 'way_3':
        y = three_ways.way_3(x1, x2)
    else:
        print('Not implemented yet')
    return y
```

So could you please help me with building such a function? It should be efficient, elegant, pythonic, and no if-elif statement. I am using Python3.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pass the function you want to call as an argument :) You can introspect in python so you can lookup the method you want in the package. But since you already know the "way" just pass it in or call it.

Comment: @Rob, thanks for your suggestion. My issue is I need to use a string in my main file to specify which `way_x()` to call. So I cannot pass the function as an argument. Because I am designing an user interface. The user will type the function name, and the program will read the typed name as string, and call the corresponding function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do exactly what you described, you can look the function up using `getattr`:

```
way_func = getattr(three_ways, way)
y = way_func(x1, x2)
```

But because Python supports first-class-functions (functions can be passed around just like other data types), it's preferable to do what Rob said, which is just passing the function itself:

```
def get_y(x1, x2, way_func):
    return way_func(x1, x2)
get_y(4, 2, three_ways.way_2)
```

Comment: thanks for your help. My issue is I need to use a string in my main file to specify which `way_x()` to call. So I cannot pass the `way_func` as an argument. Because I am designing an user interface. The user will type the function name, and the program will read the typed name as string, and call the corresponding function.